# CMake import non-compiled files into build directory

Tags: build, copy, cmake

I use CMake like that:

```
$ mkdir build && cd build
$ cmake .. && make && atf-run | atf-report
```

But to run atf I need some files (for example /Atffile and test/Atffile), so I'm looking for a way to import in my build directory all that kind file.

I tried this:

```
file(COPY ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/.. DESTINATION ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/..)
```

But it doesn't work. Is their a simple/cleaner way to do it?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Assuming "/Atffile" and "/test/Atffile" are files and not folders, you can use [`configure_file`][1]

```
configure_file(Atffile Atffile COPYONLY)
configure_file(test/Atffile test/Atffile COPYONLY)
```

Since the commands here use relative paths throughout, the input arg is relative to the current source directory and the output arg is relative to the current binary (i.e. build) directory.

[1]: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/configure_file.html "CMake documentation for "configure_file" command"

Comment: this may result in unnecessary cmake reruns

Comment: First argument is input, second is output.

Answer (score 2):

I use the following to copy a complete directory into the build directory

```
file(COPY "datasets" DESTINATION "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}")
```

Comment: I've also had success with 
`file(COPY "datasets" DESTINATION .)`